# Using LINQ to evaluate expressions from a string against a datatable

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic-linq

I am trying to write something that will allow custom expressions be stored in strings to be evaluated against various data.  After several failed attempts I was able to find something successful, but it doesn't lend itself to the intent.

```cs
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Age", typeof(int)));

dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "John", 32 });

var test = dt.AsEnumerable().AsQueryable();

// An example of an expression to test
string expression = "Age = 32";

// Failed Attempts
//var result1 = test.Where(expression); // Error received:  {"No property or field 'Age' exists in type 'DataRow'"}
//var result2 = test.Where("it.Field<object>(\"Age\") == 32");  // Error received:  {"No property or field 'Field' exists in type 'DataRow'"}
//var result3 = test.Where("Age=@0", 32);  // Error received:  {"No property or field 'Age' exists in type 'DataRow'"}
//var result4 = test.Where("it[\"Age\"] == 127"); // Error received:  {"Operator '==' incompatible with operand types 'Object' and 'Int32'"}
//var result5 = test.Where("it[\"Age\"] = 127");  // Error received:  {"Operator '=' incompatible with operand types 'Object' and 'Int32'"}
//var result6 = test.Where("it[\"Age\"] as Age  = 127");  // Error received:  {"Expression of type 'Boolean' expected"}

// Successful but at this point its not really a dynamic linq expression
var result = test.Where(it => it.Field<int>("Age") == 32);
```

How can I accomplish this?  All roads seems to lead back to this article:  http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx  But I do not see the answer to what I am trying to do as he is using strongly typed data.

Thanks!

Comment: It's not `linq` but would the [`DataTable.Select()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.select.aspx) method be helpful?

Comment: I Have never tried using Dynamic Linq with a DataTable.  And Im wondering if you would consider an option where you are not using a DataTable?

Comment: this will work: dt.Select("Age=32"); and this will work too: dt.AsEnumerable().Where(a => a["Name"].Equals("John"));

Comment: DaveParsons and Arie right, but now I'm a little confused.  Why does Select("Age=32") work and Where("Age=32") not work?  I only used Where to begin with because I thought it was intended for filtering?

Comment: @jrandomuser They're entirely unrelated methods of querying a `DataTable`.  One is specific to `DataTable` and has been around ages longer.  The other is LINQ, which isn't just specific to data tables, but has a very different method of querying.

Comment: Truth be told I'm getting the actual values from a DataReader, I only put them into a DataTable because expressions can only be tested against collections that I know of.  Should I be doing this differently at all?

Comment: @jrandomuser Can you just use Entity Framework instead of a `DataReader`?  The Dynamic LINQ framework that you've referenced is designed to be used with such a LINQ query provider, rather than for `DataTable` objects.

Comment: @Servy Ohhhhh, I've been confusing the Select off of DataTable with the Select from Linq, but I just realized you're right.  I used Select from DataTables long before Linq.

Comment: @Servy I wish I could but I don't have control over the data layer.  I basically get a datareader to loop through and one or more expressions as strings that they want me to use to evaluate the data and do SomeAction().  There are different sets of data that are run, each one with their own customization expressions I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want use DynamicLINQ you need change your code.

1) this expression

```
// Failed Attempts
string expression = "Age = 32";
var result1 = test.Where(expression); // Error received:  {"No property or field 'Age' exists in type 'DataRow'"}
```

is same

```
// Failed Attempts
var result1 = test.Where("Age = 32"); // Error received:  {"No property or field 'Age' exists in type 'DataRow'"}
```

so DynamicLinq try find property `Age` for *DataRow* and since *DataRow* class don't have this property you get error **No property or field 'Age' exists in type 'DataRow'**

---

2) in this expression

```
var result2 = test.Where("it.Field<object>(\"Age\") == 32");  // Error received:  {"No property or field 'Field' exists in type 'DataRow'"}
```

DynamicLinq try find property or method `Field`, but it is extension method in [DataRowExtensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.datarowextensions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), so you also get error **No property or field 'Field' exists in type 'DataRow'**

---

3) this expression is same as first with using parameters

```
var result3 = test.Where("Age=@0", 32);  // Error received:  {"No property or field 'Age' exists in type 'DataRow'"}
```

---

Next two expression equivalent, becuase when DynamicLinq parse expression, it parse both `=` and `==` as `Equals`

```
var result4 = test.Where("it[\"Age\"] == 127"); // Error received:  {"Operator '==' incompatible with operand types 'Object' and 'Int32'"}
var result5 = test.Where("it[\"Age\"] = 127");  // Error received:  {"Operator '=' incompatible with operand types 'Object' and 'Int32'"}
```

if you see about [DataRow.Item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/146h6tk5.aspx) property you can see that it return `Object`, so for checking equals you need cast object result to `int` something like this

```
var result4 = test.Where("Convert.ToInt32(it[\"Age\"]) == 127");
```

also, possibly, in this case you can help paramtrize form like this

```
var result4 = test.Where("it[\"Age\"] == @0",127);
```

---

at last here

```
var result6 = test.Where("it[\"Age\"] as Age  = 127");  // Error received:  {"Expression of type 'Boolean' expected"}
```

after parsing expression DynamicLinq get lambda that don't return `Boolean`, so you get error **Expression of type 'Boolean' expected**

Answer (score -1):

This should get you what you're looking for.  Put in your null checking in case there are no columns that match the supplied string name etc...

```
int age = 32;
string column = "Age";

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Age", typeof(int)));

dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "John", 32 });

var result = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(r => Convert.ToInt32(r[column]) == age);
```